# How can I make the program check if input = sorted list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I created a program which takes user input of integers spaced out and sorts them in a list by ascending (lowest to highest) order without the sort function. I'm trying to output "Sorted" or "not sorted" based on if the list is or isn't in ascending order but for some reason it doesn't work. here's my code:

```
         c = input("Enter list values all on one line, separated by space\n")
values = c.split()
compare=c.split

for i in range (0,len(values)):
    values[i]=int(values[i])

print("Original list:", values)

for i in range(len(values)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(values)):
        if values[i]>values[j]:
            values[j],values[i]=values[i],values[j]
        
print("New list:", values)

if compare != values:
        print("Not in order")

if compare == values:
        print("In order")
```

Comment: The variable c is a string, while values is a list. You can't compare the two.

Comment: so should I store the input in a blank list and then compare that list with values?

Comment: Also your indentation is really off. You shouldn't be performing the check until the very end.

Comment: i updated the code and what i did still isn't working

Comment: You need to fix your indentation of the first line. and you need to fix this line: `compare= c.split()` - note the parentheses ()

Answer (score 0):

There are few syntax error. `compare = c.split()` instead of `compare = c.split`.

In your first loop include `compare[i] = int(compare[i])` in order to compare the the sorted list which has integer values to the unsorted list which has string values.

```py
c = input("Enter list values all on one line, separated by space\n")
values = c.split()
compare = c.split()

for i in range (len(values)):
    values[i]=int(values[i])
    compare[i] = int(compare[i])

print("Original list:", values)

for i in range(len(values)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(values)):
        if values[i]>values[j]:
            values[j],values[i]=values[i],values[j]
        
print("New list:", values)

if compare != values:
        print("Not in order")

if compare == values:
        print("In order")
```